# How to get the height of navbar when toggle in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if this question is acceptable or not but I just can't find any answer on google.

I have navbar with toggle button for mobile

```html
<!-- Mobile Menu Toggle Button -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="navbar-small-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
        aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-awesome fas fa-bars"></span>
    <span class="navbar-toggler-awesome fas fa-times"></span>
</button>
<!-- end of mobile menu toggle button -->
```

I want to get the height of the navbar after each toggle

```js
$("#navbar-small-toggle").click(function() {
    console.log($("nav").height());
})
```

with my code above it gave me this

```
74  312  74  312 ......
```

but what i want is

```
312  74  312  74 ...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: i dont understand your problem, if the program gives 74 in first, its just the reality.. why you want 312 in first?

Comment: it's because i want to get height after toggle so that my search box can have the exact same location. I just solved it myself and i will answer this question once im free